# How to get mp3 info in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

Creating a music player for android with Apache Cordova, I hit a block trying to get song info (artist, album) from mp3s.
I tried just using the directory structure (one directory up from mp3 = album, two up = artist) but that was unreliable.
So now I've been trying to read the ID3 information from the mp3 files to get the artist and album tags, but everything I've tried is either coming up blank or crashing the app. Any ideas??

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, fsSuccess);

  function fsSuccess(fs){
    console.log(fs);
    var dirURL = fs.root.nativeURL;
    directoryPath = dirURL.replace("file://", "");
    gotPath(directoryPath)
  }
  function gotPath(directoryPath) {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(directoryPath, {create: false, exclusive: false}, getDirSuccess);
    })
  }
  function getDirSuccess(dirEntry) {
    var directoryReader = dirEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(readerSuccess);
  }
  function readerSuccess(entries) {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
        if(entries[i].isDirectory) {
            directoryURL = entries[i].nativeURL;
            directoryPath = directoryURL.replace("file://", "");
            gotPath(directoryPath);
        } if (entries[i].isFile){
            if(entries[i].name.indexOf(".mp3") != -1){
                var fileURL = entries[i].localURL.replace("file://", "");
                ID3.loadTags(fileURL, function() {
                    var tags = ID3.getAllTags(fileURL);
                    alert(tags.artist);
                },
                {
                    tags: ["artist"]
                },
                {
                    dataReader: FileAPIReader(fileEntry.file)

                }); 
            }
        }
    }
  }
}, false);
```

I'm trying to use this library to read the ID3 info with [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader).

**EDIT**

I was able to get this working for a single file, but I'm still having trouble trying to get the info while looping through the files.

Here's the code to get the ID3 info from a single file (passing the selected song in via an ng-click event):

```
$scope.getInfo = function (song) {
    filePath = song.nativeURL;
    file_URI = filePath.replace("file://", "");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(file_URI, null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }
    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }
    function gotFile(fileEntry){
        ID3.loadTags(fileEntry.localURL, function() {
                var tags = ID3.getAllTags(fileEntry.localURL);
                console.log(tags.artist + " " + tags.album + " " + tags.title + " " + tags.track);
            },
            {
                tags: ["artist", "album", "track", "title"]
            });
    }
    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
};
```

Comment: How about sharing the code with what you tried to get the ID3 information out of the files?